# jQuery: Array Breaks at Space

Tags: jquery, html

I'm storing a set of names in an Array in `localStorage` as such: 
 `"namesEdited", ["Steve R.", "Steve N.", "JR T.", etc.]`

The contents of `"namesEdited"` gets put into `memList` early in the code. When I use `console.log` to see what `memList` has for the Array values upon loading the page, it displays like written above. However, when I load each value (via a `for` loop) into the html code, it only displays `Steve` instead of `Steve R.` On top of that, it doesn't put the last name initial in the next box either; it only displays first names (ex. the `memList` gets displayed as `Steve`, `Steve`, `JR`, etc). What gives?

.js code: 
    `for (m = 0; m < memList.length; m++) {
      $('.idName[num="' + m + '"]').html('<input type="text" name="memberName" value=' + memList[m] + '>');
      }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string character you are using is the `'` character.  So if you look at your concatenation you are doing

```
value='+ thing +'
```

This will result is something like

```
value=Steve R.
```

Since you are not puting quotes around it, the value stops at the first space.  Change your script to put the string into quotes.

```
value="'+ thing +'"
```

Optionally you could use a template literal to do the same thing

```
.html(`<input type="text" name="memberName" value="${memList[m]}">`)
```

For template literals though, be aware of browser support.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literal